# Is there an iOS alternative to openssl's EVP_BytesToKey?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, openssl, commoncrypto

I want to make an **AES 256 CBC key and iv with SHA1 digest** like in openssl's `EVP_BytesToKey` function, **but with iOS tools**. Is there an iOS alternative for that?

In openssl it looks like:

```
int ret = EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_aes_256_cbc(), EVP_sha1(), salt, keyingData, strlen(keyingData), 2048 /*iteration*/, resultKey, resultIV);
```

Later I want to use that generated key (`resultKey`) and iv (`resultIV`) in CommonCrypto's `CCCrypt`, but I don't know how to generate them with iOS tools. Please help.

### UPDATE

I've found a code snippet in [this video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/709), which maybe do the job, but I'm not sure. Also it's just the key, the IV is still unknown to me.

```
let keyByteCount = 256/8
var key = Array(repeating: 0, count: keyByteCount)
let error = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, keyByteCount, &key)
if error != errSecSuccess {
    return 1
}
memset_s(&key, keyByteCount, 0, keyByteCount)
```

But I think this is not what I'm looking for, because it doesn't require a salt or iteration count or any algorithm (like SHA1).

Comment: https://github.com/rnapier/RNOpenSSLCryptor  The specific part you're looking for is probably https://github.com/rnapier/RNOpenSSLCryptor/blob/master/RNOpenSSLCryptor.m#L66-L99

Comment: @RobNapier Thanks, I managed to do this based on this article [link](https://robnapier.net/aes-commoncrypto)